# Oracle spatial - get sdo_geometry information as an output of a select

Tags: sql, oracle, geometry

I have a table with point features in Oracle Spatial and I am trying to select distinct features by combining its name and date and counting its occurrences during a period.

The problem is that I can't get the spatial information (`sdo_geometry` type) in the output.

```
select 
  a.feature_name,  
  count(distinct(a.feature_name||trunc(a.date,'DD'))) as number_of_days,  
  first(geometry) -- < --- the problem is here!  
from table a 
where 
  a.date >=to_date('01/01/2016 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
  and a.date<to_date('02/01/2016 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
group by a.feature_name;
```

Comment: select a.feature_name,    count(distinct(a.feature_name||trunc(a.date,'DD'))) as number_of_days, first(geometry) <--- the problem is here! from table a where a.date >=to_date('01/01/2016 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY    HH24:MI:SS') and a.date<to_date('02/01/2016 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY  HH24:MI:SS') group by a.feature_name;

Comment: You need to post code in the question

Comment: proper code formatting makes it easier to read. You say there is some problem, but you don't explain what that problem is. It's really hard to see your screen from here. If you get an error message, please post it in its entirety.